# How to make reference variable dynamic? I want this #parent.menuTrigger to be dynamic

Tags: angular

I want to make reference variable dynamic from looping value

```
<mat-nav-list appAccordion *ngFor="let parent of menus">
  <mat-list-item div appAccordionLink [matMenuTriggerFor]="parent.menuTrigger">
    <a>
      <mat-icon>{{parent.icon}}</mat-icon><span>{{parent.caption}}</span>
    </a>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-menu #parent.menuTrigger="matMenu" *ngFor="let child of parent.childs">
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="[child.routerLink]">{{child.caption}}</button>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: You can not, but don't worry because it's unnecesary, as all is under a *ngFor Angular ["know the scope"](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope), that's if you use `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menuTrigger"` you simply use `#menuTrigger`. IF you want get it in code (in the .ts) you need use ViewChildren instead ViewChild